# visual studio 2012 mingw and format error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mingw

I'm taking a c++ class and the instructor has stated that we can use any IDE that we like however, he will be compiling our .cpp and .h files using mingw. I'm using Visual Studio 2012. How should be creating projects using VS2012 to ensure that they will compile with mingw? Can I start the project as win32 or should I use a general empty project? Compilers and dll's are an enigma to me.

I also have code::blocks installed from a previous class and then just to really screw up my default settings and directories I downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2015 in an attempt to upgrade. I have since uninstalled VS2015 and all of the other software that installed at the same time. Now, anytime I start a new project in VS2012 I get the error:

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format
>   (Exception from HRESULT 0X8007000B)

I suspect that when I installed VS2015 something changed where my x86 VS2012 is looking trying to use x64 or something other than Visual Studio 11.

I'd love to fix that glitch if you can help.

Thanks

Comment: Is there something in VS that you can't live without for this project? If the instructor will be compiling with mingw and it's a requirement that he/she is able to compile your code, then why not just use mingw + code::blocks?

Comment: It seems like Visual Studio is the preferred IDE in the industry, I'd like to learn how to use it now.

Comment: _"It seems like Visual Studio is the preferred IDE in the industry"_ That would be highly dependent on where you work. I've been developing mainly in C and C++ at work for the past 9 years, in different projects, and the last time I used VS was probably back in 2009. It's your choice - I'm just saying why complicate things for this course? You can still use VS for some spare time projects if you want to learn it. As far as your VS problems go, you should probably do a fresh install of the version you want to use.

Comment: If I perform the clean install, should I also uninstall all of the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable packages?